# Anyway to Execute Google App Script Code Hosted on GHE

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to find a way to run Google App Script code that's hosted on GHE. I found somewhere that you could get the script as a text string and use eval() to execute it as code, however I've read that it's a very unsecure way to do it and it shouldn't be done. Does anyone know any alternatives ways to run hosted code on Google App Script?

Comment: Use the [tag:google-apps-script-api]

Comment: What does GHE stand for ? Do you want to run/create/change Apps Script projects remotely from this host?

Comment: GHE stands for GitHub Enterprise. Correct, but i'd ideally want to both host the code on GHE and execute it in Google App Script.

@TheMaster, I think that's the best option, thanks! I don't know if I'll fully be able to use it with the current restrictions I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. use this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo
2. use git and clasp CLI to push your code to your apps script project

Comment: Thanks! That would probably work under regular circumstances, but I didn't give enough context. Chrome Extensions aren't an option for me. I think the best option is the Google App Scripts API. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your specifications, I understand that you want to both host the script in GitHub Enterprise (GHE) and run it from there.

Even though [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) offers a good range of functionalities such as [executing functions from your App remotely](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute) it is not the best option for this scenario.

With [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) you can also write Apps Script functions remotely but eventually they have to be pushed to an Apps Script project.

So, after considering these limitations I think the best option you would have is to use the right [Google API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) in your script (such as [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) for example). Its functional code can all be **hosted and run** from your application without the need of Apps Script projects and these APIs offer the same and **extended functionalities** than those offered by Apps Script.